# Content Values and SQL injection

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-injection

Does this construction prevent SQL-injection?

```
ContentValues localContentValues = new ContentValues();
localContentValues.put("some_column", StringFromUser);
localSQLiteDatabase.update("some_table", localContentValues, null, null);
```

Comment: No where is your whereArgs?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial, http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html I always take a look at this one when I have some doubt about SQLite on Android

Comment: or go to this :[http://learnandroid.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-database.html](http://learnandroid.blogspot.in/2008/01/android-database.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ContentValues` [uses variable binding behind the scenes](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java#1537). So yes, it's not vulnerable to the usual SQL injections.